# ng-lightning - data object is undefined on lookup

Tags: angular, ng-lightning

I'm working with the Lookup component and am getting an error that my data object is undefined and thus cannot .filter(). Code is below:

```
getAllAccounts() {
    this._quickAddService.getAllAccounts()
        .subscribe(
        accounts => this.getAllAccountsFinished(accounts),
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}

getAllAccountsFinished(accounts:any) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
    console.log(this.accounts);

    this.hideSpinner();
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.getAllAccounts();
}

lookup(query: string): Account[] {
    if (!query) {
        return null;
    }

    return this.accounts.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase())>-1);
}
```

that console.log is showing that the data is bound properly once the service finishes returning. However when lookup is fired on input this.accounts is undefined.

Comment: Where is `lookup` called from?

Comment: it is a property bound to the element in the template:

    `<ngl-lookup [lookup]="lookup" field="name" (pick)="onPick($event)"    debounce="0" placeholder="Hint: type words">
                <span nglLookupLabel>Quick search an account</span>
            </ngl-lookup>`

Comment: Thats why it is usually better in Angular to create an `@Output() lookup = new EventEmitter()` in `<ngl-lookup>` and bind to it like `<ngl-lookup (lookup)="lookup($event)" ` than passing around functions.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer Yes that's true, but in our case there is some "gymnastic" that I don't want to let user handle it ;) https://github.com/ng-lightning/ng-lightning/blob/master/src/lookups/lookup.ts#L100

Comment: I see. Seems reasonable. Thanks for the feefback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by @bekos on the [Gitter](https://gitter.im/ng-lightning/ng-lightning?at=573586951794136a7d08410d). Need to add binding to component constructor:

```
constructor(elementRef:ElementRef, private _quickAddService:QuickAddService) { 
    this.visible = true;

    this.lookup = this.lookup.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Yup, was my suspicion :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response though! On top of it :)

Comment: I tried, says I have to wait two days to mark my own answer. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just a small comment regarding this ;-)

It's perhaps better to wrap your lookup method instead of using the `bind` method in TypeScript because you will lose type checking.

Something like this:

```
this.lookup = (query) => {
  this.lookup(query);
};
```

See this link for more details:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html